# How to make attributes in data class non null in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have a data class in Kotlin - where there are 5-6 fields,

```
data class DataClass(
    val attribute1: String?,
    val attribute2: String?,
    val attribute3: Boolean?
)
```

i can initialise the class with `DataClass(attribute1="ok", attribute2=null, attribute3= null)`

Is there any way to prevent null values in data class ?

Comment: The point of `?` is to allow null values, so just remove it.

Comment: var attribute2: String = "", var attribute3: Boolean = false, like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kotlin's type system uses `?` to declare nullability](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html). Your data class has fields which are nullable. You can prevent them from being `null` by removing the `?` from their types:

```
data class DataClass(
    val attribute1: String, // not `String?`
    val attribute2: String, // not `String?`
    val attribute3: Boolean // not `Boolean?`
)

fun main() {
    // This line will compile
    val tmp = DataClass(attribute1 = "", attribute2 = "", attribute3 = false)

    // This line will not compile
    val fail = DataClass(attribute1 = null, attribute2 = null, attribute3 = null)
}
```